# Alternative methods of solving Sudoku

Tags: java, beginner, recursion, sudoku

I am learning Java as my first programming language and have written a bit of code. I would love to read expert reviews on this code and suggestions to improve right from naming conventions to logic. Please let me know if there is any kind of mistake.

```
public class Sudoku {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[][] array = { { 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0 },
                          { 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 4 }, 
                          { 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                          { 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7 }, 
                          { 0, 7, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                          { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0 }, 
                          { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 8, 9, 0, 2 },
                          { 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0 }, 
                          { 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 } };
        solve(array);
        System.out.println("Solution is ");
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                System.out.print(" " + array[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Time taken (in MilliSeconds)= " + totalTime);
    }

    public static boolean solve(int[][] array) {
        if (isSum45(array)) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                if (array[row][col] == 0) {
                    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
                        if (noConflict(array, row, col, num)) {
                            array[row][col] = num;
                            if (solve(array)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        array[row][col] = 0;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // This method edited is after taking suggestions from this forum
    public static boolean noConflict(int[][] array, int row, int col, int num) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
            if (array[row][k] == num) {
                return false;
            }
            if (array[k][col] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        int m = row - (row % 3);
        int n = col - (col % 3);
        for (int p = m; p < m + 3; p++) {
            for (int q = n; q < n + 3; q++) {
                if (array[p][q] == num) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isSum45(int[][] array) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                int sum = 0;
                int m = row - (row % 3);
                int n = col - (col % 3);
                for (int p = m; p < m + 3; p++) {
                    for (int q = n; q < n + 3; q++) {
                        sum = sum + array[p][q];
                    }
                }
                if (sum != 45) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your noConflict is a waste of processor. You should be looking only for the number you try to set, so instead of: add to list every number in row and column, check if num is in the list, return; you can only do: check if number is in row or column, return when found. It will be much faster.

Comment: @fernando.reyes I couldn't get your point correctly. What if the number is in the current grid? With that in mind I wrote like that.

Comment: I miss that part, let's rephrase it. The first `for` with two ifs, instead of adding everything to the list, `if (array[row][k] == num ) return false;` and that saves some loop cycles

Comment: @fernando.reyes I changed the code as suggested by you. Thanks once again.

Comment: Sudoku was the topic of a recent [WeekEnd Challenge](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=[weekend-challenge]+sudoku) here on CodeReview. you should consider scanning those answers for ideas. Additionally, there is a relatively comprehensive Java solution on the [CodeReview GitHub](https://github.com/CodeReviewCommunity/Java-Sudoku-Solver) which may provide some inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

Overall, this is pretty good code for a beginner's solution to a relatively complex problem.

But your code *does* have me a little lost.  For one, I'm not quite sure why you're using recursion here.  It seems like that will be a *lot* more memory intensive than it needs to be for a straightforward problem.  It also confused me for a good ten minutes why you were checking for `isSum45` to return that the problem is solved, when the sum for the entire board is actually 405.

I would rewrite this as an iterative solution rather than a recursive solution.  I think the recursion adds a lot of unnecessary complexity to the code and flow.  I don't have the time at the moment to rewrite it as such, so I'll just give some other general comments on your code.

```
solve(array);
System.out.println("Solution is ");
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I'm not a big fan of the above implementation because it relies on the `solve()` method modifying the original array in place.  It also makes your paradigm of returning a `boolean` from the `solve()` method irrelevant; you never compare or check for it.  I think it would be a better design if you *preserve* the original board and create a new `int[][] solved` variable which you return from the method.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] == 0) {
            for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
                if (noConflict(array, row, col, num)) {
                    array[row][col] = num;
                    if (solve(array)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                array[row][col] = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

On a positive note, I really like that you named your loop variables `row` and `col` versus `i` and `j` as so many people do.  It makes your code much more readable.  But one of the principles of good code design is to avoid this kind of intense nesting as much as possible.  You can do this like the following:

```
for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    for(int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
        if(array[row][column] != 0) continue;
        for(int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
            if(!noConflict(array, row, column, num)) continue;
            array[row][column] = num;
            if(solve(array)) return true;
            array[row][column] = 0
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This makes your code a bit less complex and a bit more readable.  I completely avoid your `if(solve(array))` block by simply returning the boolean directly from the recursive method call (**EDITED**: As David Harkness says in the comments below, this actually changes how the method functions, so I've removed that bit.).  Also note that it my loops I compare `row` and `column` to `array.length` and `array[row].length`, respectively.  This isn't a huge deal if you always know you're going to be handling boards which are 9x9, however when you're designing code you should always try to make your code as flexible as possible.  The more flexible it is and the more scenarios it can handle, the more powerful it is.

```
public static boolean noConflict(int[][] array, int row, int col, int num) {
```

This is just general nitpicking, but you should only expose methods as `public` which actually need to be `public`.  The `solve` method makes sense as a `public` method because it's the part of the API that you will want to use in other parts of the application.  This method, however, is purely internal and thus should be `private`.  Also, method names should pretty much always be verbs or verb phrases.  I might rename this method to something like `noConflictExists` or `isNoConflict`.  Actually, because of the nature of how I rewrote your loops above, I would change it to `conflictExists` or `isConflict` that way my usage of it is more intuitive.  These notes also apply to your `isSum45` method, which is `public` and might use a more intuitive name for code readability.

Also, in those two methods, what happened to your beautiful variable names?!?  Why did you suddenly move to using single letters instead of something more descriptive?

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation and review. Do you really think that the sudoku can be solved based on your rewrite of solve()? Please check once and let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: The isSum45() is actually the base case for the recursive backtracking algorithm. This condition will be met only when the entire board is filled with the correct numbers i.e. 1 to 9 whose sum is actually 45. The method checks whether the sub grids follow the rule of the game or not. Hope you got my point.

Comment: @Phoenix Sure.  My rewrite doesn't actually change any of the functionality of your code, just the readability by reducing the number of nestings.  I'm sure your method does work great for the recursion. :)

Comment: You can't simply return the result of the recursive call to `solve`. If the result is `false` you must try the next number, or it will give up on the first incorrect guess. While I've found the recursive brute-force approach to be the simplest to implement and understand, you do make other good points so +1.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Ah, good point.  When skimming it, my brain only processed the `if(true) return true` style.  Will fix. :)

Comment: @Jeff Gohlke Please try fixing the suggestions. It doesn't solve sudoku. I tried today too.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Add  array[row][column] = 0; immediately after if (solve(array)). Then it will be fixed.

Comment: @Phoenix That was something I was confused by as well.  Why are you setting the solution to whatever number, then unsetting it again?  It seems like another example of how your design is quite convoluted.  In any case, I added the line.  My apologies for missing it while skimming your code.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Thanks a lot for your insightful review. The solution that I have arrived at is actually the simplest of all, I think. May be you didn't spend time why that zero being assigned after that if() clause. Spend some time. If you find an easier solution than this, kindly let me know as the title of this post also reflects the same. Thanks once again.